# How to change all links in website using javascript by adding "?lang=el"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace all my links in my website. Howeverm this code replaces all the link, however I have to **add** at the end a `"?lang=en"`

How can I change this?

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    {
        links[i].href = "newURLHERE";
    }
```

Comment: seems like you are replacing all `href` instead append text try like this `links[i].href += "newURLHERE";` or `links[i].href = links[i].href + "newURLHERE";`

Answer (score 0):

Using `=` replaces the whole `href` attribute.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    Array.from(links).forEach(function(v) {
      /\?/.test(v.href) ? v.href += "&lang=en" : v.href += "?lang=en";
    });
```

```html
<a href='something3'>click1</a>
<a href='something2'>click2</a>
<a href='page.php?var=a&var=b'>click3</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It works. I have one scenario that I have to pass... some of my original links are in the form of `page.php?var=a&var=b` so the added in these case only must be `&lang=en` instead of `?lang=en`.
How to do this?

Comment: @Pashiamas You could check with test function if given href already contains `?` sign. If so - add the link with `&` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.indexOf` Just added another approach to check query-string exist or not  in @Kind user's answer as i like the way he's using `Arrow functions`

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    Array.from(links).forEach(v => 
    (v.href.indexOf("?") > -1) ? v.href += "&var=c" : v.href += "?var=d");
```

```html
<a href='something3?var=a'>click1</a>
<a href='something2'>click2</a>
<a href='something1'>click3</a>
```